# Sqoop - Custom sink

Tags: apache, hadoop, sqoop

I'd like to be able to import data with Sqoop into a custom Hadoop data store.  This would be the equivalent of importing from an arbitrary structured DB (MySql, Netezza, etc) to my own custom data store (in this case, equivalent of Hive)

Any pointers for creating this custom sink and integrating with Scoop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is  no support for creating a custom sink with sqoop. But you can create a custom sinks using flume and flume has ability to load from data sources.

BTW, What is the custom Hadoop data store?. What format it stores and how different is from hadoop.

I would suggest you to use  **flume-ng-sql-source** plugin for flume and then import data to your custom sink.

The following links may help you to use flume-ng-sql-source.

https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11114.streaming-mysql-database-table-data-to-hdfs-with-flume

https://github.com/keedio/flume-ng-sql-source

To write a custom sink follow the [custom sink docs](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeDeveloperGuide.html#sink). Custom source is in the same documentation.